# react-router-dom 'Link' is not working just for one part of code and working perfectly fine elsewhere. What's the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here I'm fetching the data from the API and storing it into state to show it on screen. Here is `details.js`

```
<div className="h2 mt-4">More Like This</div>
            <div class="container-fluid overflow-auto">
                <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
                {SimilarMovies && SimilarMovies.map((similarmovie, index) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={index}>
                            <GridCard 
                                image={similarmovie.poster_path && `${IMAGE_URL}w500${similarmovie.poster_path}`}
                                similarMovieId={similarmovie.id} movieTitle={similarmovie.title} name={similarmovie.original_title}
                            />  {/*this will go to else part of gridcard */}
                        </React.Fragment>
                ))}
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* actor button */}
            <div className="text-center mt-2">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}> View Actors</button>
            </div>

            {/* actors grid */}
            {ActorToggle &&
            <Row>
                {Crews && Crews.map((crew, index) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        {crew.profile_path &&
                        <GridCard 
                            actor={crew.name} character={crew.character} image={`${IMAGE_URL}original${crew.profile_path}`}
                        />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </Row>}
```

in this code `<Gridcard>` which appears first is having problem, data displayed Link is not working but it changes in url so if I refresh the page, I'll go to that page. The another `<Gridcard>` below is working fine.

here is `Gridcard.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Col } from 'reactstrap';
function GridCard(props) {

if(props.actor) {
    return(
        <Col lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={6} className="mb-3 mt-3">
            <div>
                    <img className="card card-img border-0" style={{ width: '100%', height: '300px' }} alt="img" src={props.image} />
                    <div className="text-center text-dark font-weight-bold card-footer">
                        <div>{props.actor} as {props.character}</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}
else if(props.movieId) {
    return(
        <Col lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={6} className="mb-3">
            <div>
                <Link to={`/movie/${props.movieId}`} className="text-decoration-none">
                    <img className="card border-0" style={{ width: '100%', height: '330px' }} alt="img" src={props.image} />
                </Link>
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}
else {
    return(
        <Col lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={6} className="mb-3">
            <div>
                <Link to={`/movie/${props.similarMovieId}`} className="text-decoration-none">
                    <img className="card border-0" style={{ width: '100%', height: '330px' }} alt="img" src={props.image} />  
                </Link>  {/*this one is not working*/}
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}
}


export default GridCard;
```

here is my `Main.js` in case you need it

```
const LoginContainer = () => (
<div>
  <Route path="/login" component={Signin} />
</div>
  );

const SignupContainer = () => (
<div>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
</div>
);

const DefaultContainer = () => (
<div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <SecuredRoute path='/profile' component={Profile} />
        <SecuredRoute exact path='/movie/:Id' component={MovieDetail} />
        <SecuredRoute path='/movies' component={LandingPage} />
        <Route path='/search' component={SearchBox} />
        <SecuredRoute path='/tv/:Id' component={TvDetail} />
        <SecuredRoute path='/tv' component={TvLandingPage} />
        <Redirect to={Home} />
    </Switch>
</div>
);

class Main extends Component {

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupContainer}/>
                <Route component={DefaultContainer}/>  
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: are you sure props.similarMovieId is exist, did you try to use the working link down for test ?

Comment: yes everything works and url also changes but it doesn't render it on screen. If i refresh I'll able to go to that page. and if I replace `Link` with `<a>` it works but it refresh the page and that's not what i'm looking for.